# Command : must be run from a terminal

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, su

I have a shared hosting account, I logged using ssh. 
when I type for example `su` I had this output : 
`su: must be run from a terminal`

Is this error relative to the fact that I don't have sufficient permissions or to something else ?

Comment: Normally I'd expect that error to be an indication of there being no TTY allocated for the connection, but that doesn't make a lot of sense if you are connecting through SSH and getting a shell. Can you share the exact steps you take to get that error, starting with a `ssh -F /dev/null user@host` from your local system? (The `-F /dev/null` causes any system or user local SSH configuration to be ignored.) If you aren't authorized to use `su`, that will normally cause a much more obvious error message (though I don't recall the exact wording, and don't have a system set up where I can try it).

Comment: Is there perhaps a connection to securetty(5)?

In other words, is the tty of the ssh session
listed in /etc/securetty ? (prepend /dev/)

Comment: You say for example `su`, do you get this error for other commands?

Comment: What does the command `tty` show? Are you logging in with ssh then typing `su`, or are you running `ssh su`? What terminal emulator are you using? Are you supposed to have root access?

Comment: Trying to answer all questions : I log in with ssh (`ssh -l login@host host` I can log in, only when using this command) than type `su` (other commands works normally), when I type `tty` I have : `not a tty` .

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? Can you give more detail about what you are doing? What are you logging into and from where?

Answer (score 4):

Try the `-t` option to ssh. If that does not work try `-tt`.

`-t`      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Comment: I tried `ssh -tl root@host host` and with double t, but had the same result. 
Ps: as it is mentioned in the documentation, to login with ssh I should use a command like this `ssh -l login@host host` .

Comment: Why you login as root? and you don't need the `-l`.

Comment: I am using `-l` because I found that without adding it, I can't login . I can see this in the documentation http://dtcsupport.gplhost.com/UserDoc/FRHow-Works-clientSSH-System (The only page that I have found is in french) . If I don't use `-l` ssh don't accept my password.

Comment: I created an ssh account with "`root`" as login, so I use `root@host` for ssh

Comment: Login as root, considered harmful: Most people concerned with security disable root login. You can gain root privileges once you are logged in (I recommend `sudo`). If you also disable password authentication, thus forcing key based authentication, then you will need the key and password to get to root.